Third Conditional with Should
The Third Conditional
if + subject + past perfect, subject + modal + have + past participle
The modal verbs 'could,' 'would,' 'may' and 'might' are commonly used in the Third Conditional, but is it possible to use 'should'?
And how would that be done? What would it look like?
I am not sure how this is done.

KJV John 14:7 has "If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also: and from henceforth ye know him, and have seen him." But I don't think that should guide modern use. (Swapping "should" and "would" is quite common in different eras and dialects.)

Yes, this is possible, although not as common as the other modals that you mentioned. It commonly describes a rule that the subject was supposed to follow. It doesn't say anything about whether or not they followed the rule.
Here are some examples:

If you had gotten a low exam score, you should have gone to office hours.
If Robert had been late for work, he should have apologized.
If Meredith had seen the spilled coffee, she should have cleaned it up.
If Sophie had requested time off, she should have gotten permission to take it.
If my dog had eaten, he should have gone outside.


None of those work for me.

StudySmarter.co.uk has "If you had followed the map, we should have found the restaurant." "She should have passed the exam if she had studied harder." "You should not have had a headache if you had drunk enough water." etc. In these examples "should" expresses an expected but not inevitable outcome. Several other ESL/grammar sites also allow "should" with the third conditional, e.g. Cambridge.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. What do you mean by that? Do these examples not sound like natural sentences to you? Or are you not understanding what I am saying?

@StuartF This is a good addition! If it's okay with you, I'll edit my answer to include your citations and clearer description

@FriendlyRacoon Yeah, they don't sound like grammatical sentences to me. Well, not if the protasis is interpreted as using a backshifted/remote clause. If they just represent a time prior to another past that we're talking about, they're ok. But then they're not '3rd/backshifted/modally remote' conditionals. But, maybe it depends on how one tilts ones head as one squints at them.

@StuartF That's a completely antiquated use of should that's basically obsolete nowadays. Those examples of should are substitutes for would. No one does that any more.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore.
To be honest, I'm still not sure I'm understanding what you are saying. Could you further explain your point?
Are you noting that the sentences sound inverted? Like that "You should have gone to office hours if you had gotten a low exam score." is more natural sounding than "If you had gotten a low exam score, you should have gone to office hours." or is it something else?
